# SQL Server Query Last Moved Item

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

We have a storage system that is full. I am trying to identify items currently in the storage system that are 'inactive' (have not been moved in a long time). With this I would have an easy way of identifying which items I can remove from the system to free up those locations for active items. I want a query that will show me the date of the last movement for each item (one result per unique item). Does that make sense?

I have 2 tables, that will need to be joined using item_id.

movement_log:

```
item_id     time                        operation   container   quantity
A           2020-01-01 11:00:00.000     Load        1           90
B           2020-01-01 13:00:00.000     Load        2           30
C           2020-01-02 09:00:00.000     Load        3           10
D           2020-01-03 15:00:00.000     Load        4           7
E           2020-01-03 15:30:00.000     Load        6           220
A           2020-01-03 16:00:00.000     Load        5           20
B           2020-01-03 17:00:00.000     Unload      2           10
C           2020-01-04 09:00:00.000     Load        3           5
D           2020-01-05 11:00:00.000     Unload      4           2
D           2020-01-06 11:00:00.000     Unload      4           2
B           2020-01-06 12:00:00.000     Unload      2           10
A           2020-01-06 13:00:00.000     Unload      1           10
E           2020-01-06 14:00:00.000     Unload      6           220
```

current_item_positions:

```
item_id     container   quantity
A           1           80
B           2           10
C           3           15
D           4           3
A           5           20
C           3           15
```

Query Result:

```
item_id     last_movement               last_operation
C           2020-01-04 09:00:00.000     Load
D           2020-01-06 11:00:00.000     Unload
B           2020-01-06 12:00:00.000     Unload
A           2020-01-06 13:00:00.000     Unload
```

Any ideas for how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If I followed you correctly, you want the latest movement per `item_id`. If so, one option is to filter with a subquery:

```
select m.item_id, m.time as last_movement, m.operation as last_operation
from movement_log m
where m.time = (select max(m1.time) from movement_log m1 where m1.item_id = m.item_id)
order by last_movement
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `movement_log(item_id, time)`.

I don't see the use of table `current_item_positions` here, as all the information you need is available in `movement_log`.

Another option is `row_number()`:

```
select m.item_id, m.time as last_movement, m.operation as last_operation
from (
    select m.*, row_number() over(partition by item_id order by time desc) rn
    from movement_log m
) m
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi GMB, thanks for your reply, I will try to play around with what you have provided but I know for a fact that the current_item_position table needs to be involved to filter out all the items that are not currently in the machine (for instance, in my example tables in the original post, the query should not return item_id E.

Comment: Hi GMB, I am nearly able to get the desired result with the addition of this line in the where clause:
`AND m.item_id IN (select item_id from current_item_positions] ip)`

The only thing is that there are a few items that are in the machine in more than 1 location and I am seeing both those in my query result, I need to filter out the duplicate item_ids that have the `earliest last_movement_time`